# How to disable click event before page fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-events

I want to disable the click event before the page fully loaded. The page load takes about 45 seconds also varies depend on the internet speed. In mean time the loaded elements should not be clickable.

There are lot of links in there so only I want to disable the click event

Comment: _Provide me a solution_ ...lol

Comment: 45 seconds is way too much for a page to load.

Comment: Apart from why it's taking too long to load, you don't need to disable the click event, just disable the button after it has been submitted.

Comment: There are lot of href links in there.

Answer (score 2):

Bind the event in [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), it will ensure event is bind when all DOM is loaded. You should re-consider why page is taking too much time.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){

    });   
});
```

> While JavaScript provides the load event for executing code when a
>   page is rendered, this event does not get triggered until all assets
>   such as images have been completely received. In most cases, the
>   script can be run as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been fully
>   constructed. The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be
>   executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to
>   attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code, [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the click events on a function, and then on page load you can run this function.

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
  //make your binds here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Like I mentioned in the comment, you can disable the button after click so it's not clickable before the event call has finished executing. Something like:

```
    $('#btn').click(function(){
            $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
    });
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2McF/)**